# In a Trapezium; Length of the parallel line which goes through the diagonals' intersection point

Tags: geometry

In the trapezium shown below, $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel to each other. $AD$ and $BC$, intersect at $O$. Line $PQ$ which goes through $O$, is parallel to $DC$. If $AB=20$ and $CD=30$ what is the length of $PQ$?
 [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add $\overline{AS}$ and $\overline{PT}$ parallel to $\overline{BD}$:

[image]

Using similar triangles, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{CD}}
&=\frac{\overline{AR}}{\overline{RD}}\\
&=\frac{\overline{PS}}{\overline{CT}}\\
&=\frac{\overline{PQ}-\overline{AB}}{\overline{CD}-\overline{PQ}}
\end{align}
$$
and solving for $\overline{PQ}$, we get
$$
\overline{PQ}=\frac{2\,\overline{AB}\,\overline{CD}}{\overline{AB}+\overline{CD}}
$$
That is, $\overline{PQ}$ is the harmonic mean of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$.

Comment: .. and can be used to construct HM by ruler $ compass !

Comment: @robjohn Hey, I can see why CRD and ARD are similar. But how do we know CPT and ASP are similar to them. It seems they are not, yet you say AR/RD=PS/CT. Could you specify how you got this?

Comment: @Sorfosh: $\triangle APR$ is similar to $\triangle ACD$. Therefore, $\frac{AD}{AR}=\frac{AC}{AP}$ and thus, $$\frac{RD}{AR}=\frac{PC}{AP}$$ Next, $\triangle APS$ is similar to $\triangle PCT$. Therefore, $$\frac{PC}{AP}=\frac{CT}{PS}$$ and thus $$\frac{RD}{AR}=\frac{CT}{PS}$$ which is the reciprocal of the relation in question.